# Is it possible to create a Facebook page that I administer and block all my friends from seeing it?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I would like to create a Facebook page for a business. I'll be the sole administrator of that page. From that page, I'll schedule events.

What I would like to do is block all my friends from seeing that page. I love my friends and family, and I appreciate that they would want to "like" and support my page by saying they'll go to my events. But, my goal is to build an entirely new audience with completely different demographics. Especially when it comes to events, I don't want the feel of the event to be influenced by the presence of my friends.

I feel that this runs against Facebook's primary assumption, which is that whatever you do, you want to be as networked as possible with everyone you know. So maybe this is difficult.

What can I do to create and administer a page that is completely separate from my current group of friends on Facebook? How do I ensure the page or its events does not get announced on anyone's timeline?

Comment: If you don't tell them about it, how would they know? Facebook doesn't display the relationship between a page and its administrators unless you tell it to. I think this is a non-issue.

Comment: @AlE. But my friends could potentially come across it. For example, it's possible that a mutual third party could click "like" or attend an event, that shows up on the third parties timeline, and then that would alert a friend to the page. If, however, I can block friends from the page (without blocking myself from that friend), then that circumstance is negated.